# Calculate Screenspace Position from 3D Position in Java

Tags: java, opengl, minecraft, lwjgl

## Overview

Hi,I'm trying to calculate the screen space position of a waypoint on screen, I can't figure out the math to do so.

```java
   private Vector2f calc(float partialTicks)
    {
        // Getting the gui scale adjusted width and height
        Window window = _minecraft.getWindow();
        int width = window.getGuiScaledWidth();
        int height = window.getGuiScaledHeight();
        
        // Calculating the center of the screen
        double screenCenterX = width / 2.0;
        double screenCenterY = height / 2.0;
        
        // Getting the player from minecraft
        LocalPlayer player = _minecraft.player;
        assert player != null;
        
        // The players looking angle
        float pitch = player.getXRot();
        float yaw = player.getYRot();
        
        // The players field of view
        double fov = Math.toRadians(player.getFieldOfViewModifier() * 70f);
        float pitchRadians = (float) Math.toRadians(pitch);
        float yawRadians = (float) Math.toRadians(yaw);
        double verticalPixelPerRad = screenCenterY / fov;
        double horizontalPixelPerRad = screenCenterX / fov;
        
        
        // The players position
        double px = player.getX();
        double py = player.getY();
        double pz = player.getZ();
        
        // The warps position
        double wx = _warp.x();
        double wy = _warp.y();
        double wz = _warp.z();
        
        // Getting the delta between the players position and the position of the warp
        double dx = wx - px;
        double dy = wy - py;
        double dz = wz - pz;

        // Calculate the distance between the player and the warp
        double distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);
        
        // TODO: Calculate the screen space position of the warp point relative to the players position and rotation
        
        return new Vector2f(0,0);
        
    }
```

The github repo: https://github.com/DcmanProductions/The-Warp-Mod/blob/be5400678cfe3f05a8a0501ac9d2b9f3d04a4a63/common/src/main/java/chase/minecraft/architectury/warpmod/client/gui/waypoint/WaypointOverlay.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the issue

```java
    private static final Minecraft client = Minecraft.getInstance();
    public static final Matrix4f lastProjMat = new Matrix4f();
    public static final Matrix4f lastModMat = new Matrix4f();
    public static final Matrix4f lastWorldSpaceMatrix = new Matrix4f();
    
    public static Vector3d worldSpaceToScreenSpace(Vector3d pos)
    {
        Camera camera = client.getEntityRenderDispatcher().camera;
        int displayHeight = client.getWindow().getHeight();
        int[] viewport = new int[4];
        GL11.glGetIntegerv(GL11.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
        Vector3f target = new Vector3f();
        double dx = pos.x - camera.getPosition().x;
        double dy = pos.y - camera.getPosition().y;
        double dz = pos.z - camera.getPosition().z;
        
        Vector4f transformedCoordinates = new Vector4f((float) dx, (float) dy, (float) dz, 1.f).mul(lastWorldSpaceMatrix);
        
        Matrix4f matrixProj = new Matrix4f(lastProjMat);
        Matrix4f matrixModel = new Matrix4f(lastModMat);
        matrixProj.mul(matrixModel).project(transformedCoordinates.x(), transformedCoordinates.y(), transformedCoordinates.z(), viewport, target);
        
        return new Vector3d(target.x / client.getWindow().getGuiScale(), (displayHeight - target.y) / client.getWindow().getGuiScale(), target.z);
    }
    
    public static boolean screenSpaceCoordinateIsVisible(Vector3d pos)
    {
        return pos != null && (pos.z > -1 && pos.z < 1);
    }
```

https://github.com/DcmanProductions/The-Warp-Mod/blob/1.19.4-architectury/common/src/main/java/chase/minecraft/architectury/warpmod/client/renderer/RenderUtils.java